# Importing data to Power Query and filter if group of records has at least one conditional value

Tags: excel, powerquery

I hope I'm going to explain myself well enough. I'm importing spreadsheets from a folder into Power Query, but I want to filter out (drop) any groups of data (by a name column) where that group has at least one instance of a given value.

Example, I have a theoretical table with two columns. One has repeating names and the other has scattered values of A or B or C. I want the query to look for a group of names, then see if any of the records in that group has either and A, B or C in the second column. If found, it drops that entire group and if none, then it allows that entire group through.

I'm not sure if this is too complex for Power Query or whether I need to do this outside Excel. If the latter, what would the equivalent SQL statement be (for MS Access, as I'm trying to keep this as basic as possible)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres about 500 ways to do this. One easy way is to filter Column2 for ABC, remove that column, then remove duplicates from Column1. That give you a unique list of groups to remove, and just merge that against the original data and remove those rows

sample:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

// all unique groups from Col1 that have a/b/c in Col2
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Column2] = "a" or [Column2] = "b" or [Column2] = "c")),
#"Removed Columns"= Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Column1"})
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"),

// merge that into original table and filter
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Column1"},#"Removed Duplicates",{"Column1"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Column1"}, {"Column1.1"}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each ([Column1.1] <> null)),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Column1.1"})
in #"Removed Columns1"
```